# QGIS 3.32 / PyQGIS / Python - insert data-driven vector PDF as first page of each atlas feature

Tags: qgis, python, pdf, atlas, svg

I have a complex atlas with irregular number of pages for each feature (from 2 to 30 pages). I need to display a complex vector in full page as first page of each feature, but QGIS composer can only import raster or simple SVG images (text and images of complex SVG are "bleeding" out of the page).

Would it be possible to use Python to obtain this result? The PDF page to insert is defined by a field ("chem_pl") of the atlas coverage layer.

I have a 0-level in Python, so tell me if it's already not clear or if I need to provide more information.